BabylonNative.a[arm64][2](BabylonNative.o)) built for 'iOS'
I'm getting this error when I try to run on iOS:

Building for 'iOS-simulator', but linking in object file
(MY_PROJECT_PATH/node_modules/@babylonjs/react-native-iosandroid-0-71/ios/libs/libBabylonNative.a[arm64]2)
built for 'iOS'

I'm trying to run babylonjs in a react-native app. It works fine on android. Below is my code:
        SceneLoader.LoadAsync(MyGLTFLink, undefined, engine).then((loadScene) => {
            if (loadScene) {
                setScene(loadScene);

                // Light
                const light = new HemisphericLight("light", new Vector3(0, 1, 0), loadScene);
                light.intensity = 0.7;

                // Camera
                const camera = new ArcRotateCamera("camera", -Math.PI / 2, Math.PI / 2, -6, new Vector3(0, 2, 0), loadScene, true);
                setCamera(camera);


            } else {
                console.error("Error loading loadScene.");
            }
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.error("Error loading scene: ", error);
        });


//.... other code


            <EngineView camera={camera} displayFrameRate={true} />



